# Core Reporting API Unique visitors

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I have a problem with data returned from Core Reporting API. I used http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ tool to get the data.
Metric = ga:visitors
When I tried to get data for period - "2013-01-30" - "2013-02-06" I got "2306" for ga:visitors. After that I tried to get data for this period "2013-01-31" - "2013-02-06" - I got "2368" for ga:visitors. 
Smaller period but bigger value??
Also after I added ga:date dimension and aggregated all "2013-01-30" - "2013-02-06" results by myself I got "3024" in total...
Did anyone had the same problem?

Thanks, for any replies...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass any time-based dimensions (ga:date, ga:day, ga:week, etc), and you cannot add the row totals yourself. This is because a sum of daily or weekly unique visitors is not the same thing as the number of unique visitors from the start to the end of your start-date and end-date.

Also, omit the segment, unless you need a special one (such as mobile visits or search visits). That is, passing segment=gaid::-1 results in values not visible in the UI.

Pass a start-date, end-date and only the metric ga:visitors and you should get what you see in the UI.

Comment: Thanks,i can understand that i cannont count unique visitors in different dates and sum them since the same visitor can appear twice if i count by dates and once if google aggregate the value. what i do not understand why the number on a bigger timeframe is smaller?
shouldn't it be at least the same?